# Can't get any data on delete header with express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to delete some data to my database into an angular application.

So on click on the delete button I have this method called

```
function deleteFolder () {
  var folder = {};

  console.log(folder);
  $http.delete ('/api/v1/folders', {'id': "QPZZGZ", 'name': "MAHU"}).then (function (response) {

  });
}
```

And on my express server I have this :

app.js :

```
app.use('/api/v1/folders', folders);
```

folder.js :

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

/* DELETE home page */
router.delete('/', function(req, res){
  var data = req.body,
      values = {
        NAME : data.name,
        PNR_REF : data.id
      };

  console.log(req.body);
});
module.exports = router;
```

In the log, there is absolutely nothing (body is an empty object)

I don't know where it come from. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You 're doing it wrong, the ajax function needs to request to the same path expressed in the server side, so you have two choices :

either you rename the :

```
router.delete('/', function(req, res){
```

to  :

```
router.delete('/api/v1/folders', function(req, res){
```

Or you directly send the ajax request to the :

```
$http.delete ('/'
```

Comment: Oops my bad I have forget something into my question, I update it

Comment: since you're sending a **delete** http request you should check the **req.query** or the **req.params** no the **req.body**

Comment: Yep thats it ! I have made this :  $http.delete('/api/v1/folders/name/' + name + '/pnr/' + id) and into my server : .delete('/name/:name/pnr/:pnr' then I got it from the req.params. Thank you

Comment: glad i could help ^^ !